# How do I make a function run and finish before a loop starts in JS

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a JS file that's automatically run through an HTML script. I want the console to print out "changing to true" before it prints out "starting toggle". The reason for this is because I want the function to call an API and change the toggle "checked" states before it loads. How do I do this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for (var i=0;i<Object.keys(obj).length;i++) {
        var obj_name = Object.keys(obj)[i];
        obj_id = "#"+obj_name;
        $(obj_id).bootstrapToggle();
        console.log("starting toggle")
    }
})
$("#samplekey").ready(function() {
    checkKey("#samplekey", power_toggles["samplekey"]);
})
function checkKey(obj_id, url1){
    var http_verb = "GET";
    $.ajax({
        url: url1,
        type: http_verb
    }).done(function(data) {
        if (data == 1234) {
            $(obj_id).prop("checked", true);
            console.log("changing to true")
        }
        else
        {
            $(obj_id).prop("checked", false);
        }
    }).fail(function(data,textStatus,errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
    });
}
```

Comment: Put the loop into an extra function and call that in `done()`

Answer (score 2):

You could made this change in your code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    checkKey("#someUrl", "someUrl")
})

function checkKey(obj_id, url1) {
    var http_verb = "GET";
    $.ajax({
        url: url1,
        type: http_verb
    }).done(function(data) {

        for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(obj).length; i++) {
            var obj_name = Object.keys(obj)[i];
            obj_id = "#" + obj_name;
            $(obj_id).bootstrapToggle();
            console.log("starting toggle")
        }


        if (data == 1234) {
            $(obj_id).prop("checked", true);
            console.log("changing to true")
        } else {
            $(obj_id).prop("checked", false);
        }
    }).fail(function(data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
    });
}

$("#samplekey").ready(function() {
    checkPOEPower("#samplekey", power_toggles["samplekey"]);
})
```

And remember that Javascript is Asynchronous, this means that the code never stops for external requests or others events.

Answer (score -1):

You should make the ajax request sync. Add a property "async: false" in your codes

```
$.ajax({
    url: url1,
    type: http_verb,
    async: false
}).done(function(data) {
    if (data == 1234) {
        $(obj_id).prop("checked", true);
        console.log("changing to true")
    }
    else
    {
        $(obj_id).prop("checked", false);
    }
}).fail(function(data,textStatus,errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
});
```